# Does the sentence "I need you to make these calls for me" contain an object complement?

Tags: grammar, complements

I'm currently working on my paper and predicative constructions confuse me so much. The book I use tells that object complements can follow the *verbs of wish & intention*, but there was no word about the verb "need". However, I've seen that verb described as monotransitive and that's it. Does this verb actually belong to the verbs of wish and intention and thus can be followed by object complements? Or are there two objects? As far as I understand it, "need" seems to have a similar meaning to "want" in the following cases:

- I *need* **you to make** these calls for me.
- He *needs* **everybody back**.

I've also seen combinations like "need ***for*** someone to do something", so I'm really lost.

Comment: Object [complement](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)s are defined by syntactic theories, so it depends entirely on which syntactic theory you are using, or want to use, to analyze these examples. _Need_ is a strange verb, a semimodal, but it can have an object complement clause. The most usual type is an infinitive: an A-Equi type (_I need to go to the bathroom_), and a B-Raising type (_I need (for) there to be silence_), which can optionally retain the _for_ complementizer to mark the infinitive subject.

Comment: Initial point: object complements consist of NPs and AdjPs, but not clauses, so there's no object complement in your first ex.  It's a catenative construction with "you" as object of "need" and the subordinate infinitival clause "to make these calls for me" as catenative complement of "need". Note that "you" is the syntactic object of "need", and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.  In your other ex. a case could be made for parsing the prep "back" as a locative objective complement of "needs", as it assigns a property that is oriented towards the object "everybody".

Comment: That's not a matter of existence, but of terminology. In the theory @BillJ prefers, they don't exist, In other theories they do. I'm  not interested in arguing about it, though, since it doesn't matter except to a linguist.

Comment: The point is that clauses express predications but are not, as wholes predicative. which explains why the subordinate clause in your first example is not an objective predicative complement, but must be a catenative complement.